# Double Red Alert

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In Star Trek (Star Trek TOS, "The Conscience of the King") an overloading phaser hidden in the Captain's quarters caused him to put the ship on **Double Red Alert**.

Was this the only time the Enterprise was raised to this level of alert? I would've expected some of the other near catastrophes to have also justified Double Red Alert.

Comment: I added some more info to my answer that you might find interesting.  :-)

Comment: That was a good episode :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, this was the only instance of its use on screen.

It wasn't employed in any episode or film except **"The Conscience of the King"**, where it was used in the following scene that you referred to:

That being said, in the [James Blish written adaptation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_2) of the episode "Court Martial", double red alert *is* used during an ion storm. The double red alert does not appear in the actual episode.

When writing, Blish had adapted the episodes directly from their scripts. The double red alert that was in the script for "Court Martial" was dropped during filming.

Comment: That garbage compactor is awfully resilient.

Comment: @amarillo There were a couple of people in the chamber that it emptied into, but no one important http://tinyurl.com/go79vcq

Comment: Wow, that red alert is very red.

Comment: @Jonah: you should see *triple* red alert. Boy howdy!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It does mean changing the bulb though.